# Server diagnostic tools?

Tags: hardware, diagnostic

I have an Openfiler server that is misbehaving. Im looking for a bootable CD or similar that will tell me whether there are memory, RAID controller or similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could download the .iso for [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) and run some basic diagnostics with it.

As for things like the RAID controller, you should be able to boot into its BIOS and look at the array at least to make sure it isn't degraded.

Comment: Yep. That's what I went with.